# navigationClick() problem for more then one item on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a ListField and ObjectChoiceField.

In the navigationClick method, how do you figure out which one is selected?

In `navigationClick()` method:

```
Field field = getFieldWithFocus();
if (field instanceof ListField)         // returns false
if (field instanceof ObjectChoiceField) // returns false
if (field == myListField)               // returns false
if (field == myObjectChoiceField)       // returns false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The navigationClick() method should only fire for the object it is attached to, unlike FieldChangeListener which can be attached to more than one Field, and so the changed Field is passed as a parameter. If you want to debug it you can use System.out.println(field.toString()) and it should give you the class name of what is being clicked. Also, you may want to try using getLeafWithFocus() in case getFieldWithFocus() is returning you the Manager of the field that has focus.

Answer (score 1):

Just override `navigationClick` for both `ListField` and `ObjectChoiceField`. Then inside of each overriden methods you will only receive clicks that is related to the "owner" of the method (e.g. either `ListField` or `ObjectChoiceField`).

Comment: I think you should check Java tutorials - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html